# Old server to new server migration

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

"The string in the new server that points the application to the old SQL database. Right now the starting points to the database "FL1m-FAC-AP01V", But that is incorrect. The correct string is Database: "PS2PW020678"

This is the problem I am facing right now after migration and the web config file is given below.

[image: webconfig]

[image: serverpath]

Comment: You need to understand a little more about what you're doing, and then explain it, before anyone has a chance at pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Don't paste images - not everyone can see them.  Copy and paste the actual contents of the config file.